# Communicate with USB Modem without AT Command

Tags: linux, usb, modem, 3g, dongle

The 3G USB modem I'm using creates /dev/ttyUSB which I can send AT commands to it as a serial port.
But is there another API to communicate to a USB Modem? is it always working as a serial COM?
How to get the API like AT command list from different vendors?
I'm writing a program in C to make calls, data test and so on but the AT commands doesn't always work, many times I needed to unplug/plug the modem to get it to work again so I thought there could be another way to do that.
Debian Linux is the platform by the way.
Appreciate your answers.